# Adding to a CSV

Tags: csv, powershell

I have the following code that basically gets the servername and adds it to a CSV on a UNC.  The problem I am having is that if I run it multiple times it keeps appending the header and adding the 2nd server.

First run this is how the file looks:

```
ServerName
Server1
```

Second run this is what happens:

```
ServerName
Server1
ServerName
Server2
```

How can I prevent this so that the server just gets appended instead of the header being written each time?

This is how my code looks:

```
$servername = $env:computername

# convert string to an object, otherwise if you output to a CSV it will save the
# strings length instead of the servername

# This entry is for testing
#$servername = "test1"

$obj_list = $servername | Select-Object @{Name='ServerName';Expression={$_}}

# converts to an object and sets no header for the column
#$obj_list | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | % {$_.Replace('"','')} | select -Skip 1 | Add-Content \\test\d$\citrixservers\test1.csv 
$obj_list | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | % {$_.Replace('"','')} | Add-Content \\test\d$\citrixservers\servers.csv
```

Comment: On 2nd run you can try something like this: `$obj_list | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ServerName | Add-Content $File -Encoding UTF8`

Answer (score 1):

Skip the header if the file already exists:

```
$csv = '\\test\d$\citrixservers\servers.csv'

$skip = if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $csv) { 1 } else { 0 }

$obj_list | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType |
  Select-Object -Skip $skip |
  ForEach-Object { $_.Replace('"','') } |
  Add-Content \\test\d$\citrixservers\test1.csv
```

Comment: Thank you. Needed to put quotes around the path for csv:

"$csv = '\\test\d$\citrixservers\servers.csv'"

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Export-CSV with the -Append parameter rather than ConvertTo-Csv. Here's one way to do it.

```
$servers = @('server1','server2')
foreach ($server in $servers) {
    [pscustomobject]@{'ServerName' = $server} | Export-Csv -Append -Path C:\Servers.csv
}
```

Comment: Note that the `-Append` parameter was added in PowerShell v3 and is not available in earlier versions.